# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' after upgrading Python 3.5 to Python 3.7 for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Like what the title said, after ugrading my Python to 3.7, the camera app won't work anymore and give me errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PiCameraApp.py", line 38, in <module>
    from    AnnotationOverlay   import *
  File "/home/pi/PiCameraApp-master/Source/AnnotationOverlay.py", line 52, in <module>
    from    Dialog  import *
  File "/home/pi/PiCameraApp-master/Source/Dialog.py", line 42, in <module>
    import PIL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I've tried re-installing pillow using 'pip3 install pillow'and Successfully installed `pillow-7.2.0`  but still won't able to import PIL.
Appreciate anyone's input. Thanks

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk`?

Comment: Just did this but instead of python3-pil.imagetk, I use python-pil.imagetk then run the app using Python 2 and camera works again. Thanks for the help, duckboycool...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Python to a newer version does not replace the old version.
You can check the default `pip3` like this.

```sh
$ pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

This is an output from my computer.
On your platform, it may say `pip3` is for Python 3.5 still.

If so, you can install Pillow for your new Python 3.7 using correct `pip` version.

```sh
python3.7 -m pip install pillow
```

Comment: Hey Hotte, I've tried this but gave me different error. The camera app works in Python 2 so, I just installed some modules for it and it works now. Thanks a lot for the input.

Comment: You are right, I can still use Pyhon 3.5. to run the camera app. Complete newbie here. Learning something everyday...Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, issue was solved by specifying which python version to use to run the app (just updated my script). I'm not sure as to why the app won't work when I upgrade Python from 3.5 to 3.7. I've checked the apps documentation and found a line the say's -- tested only on Python 2.7 and Python 3.5. Anyway, camera app works again and also Thanks again for the help.